# Displaying specific elements of a collection's subcollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List collection that contains a List subcollection as a property within it, and I want to filter out items in that subcollection based on the value of certain properties.

To simplify, I'll call the main collection THING and the subcollection SUBTHING. They are different types. THINGS can have 1 to many SUBTHINGS. SUBTHING has 2 properties I want to filter by, PROP1 should equal 1 (it can equal 1,2,3) and PROP2 should not be NULL (it can contain a string).

So when I use a query like the one below it seems to give me what I want (though I'm not sure All() is doing what I expect):

```
search = from c in search
where c.SUBTHING.All(s=>s.PROP1==1)
select c;
```

Then I get suspicious when I add the other property:

```
search = from c in search
where c.SUBTHING.All(s=>s.PROP1==1 && s.PROP2 != NULL)
select c;
```

And I get THINGS that have PROP2 as Null.

When I switch to Any() I lose all filtering on SUBTHING and it shows SUBTHINGS where PROP1 = 1,2,3 and where PROP2 is NULL and not NULL.

What I'm trying to get is a collection that lists all THING IDs and then lists the Name of all SUBTHINGS, sort of like this:

```
THING.ID
     SUBTHING.Name
     SUBTHING.Name

THING.ID
     SUBTHING.Name
     SUBTHING.Name
```

Is this possible to also filter SUBTHINGS while filtering THINGS with LINQ since THING and SUBTHING are two different types?

Comment: _"What I'm trying to get is a collection that lists all **SUBTHING** IDs ..."_ is a typo and should be _"What I'm trying to get is a collection that lists all **THING** IDs ..."_ ?!

Comment: @ewomack, are you trying to modify c in search to have the exact same values of everything except SUBTHING is filtered?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want all SUBTHINGS in your entire hierarchy that have PROP1=1 and PROP2!=Null together with their corresponding THING.IDs.... is that correct?

Comment: @Tim, yes, you're right that was a typo. Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @M Afifi & DarkSquirrel, yes, you both sound correct - I'm trying to filter the subcollecton SUBTHINGS from within the hierarchy of THINGS-->SUBTHINGS.

Comment: `All` is a predicate on a collection that returns true if all elements of the collection meet that criteria. `Any` returns true if at least one element meets the criteria. What you want is all `THING`s where ANY `SUBTHING` meets the criteria, in which case you're going to project the `THING`s ID and all `SUBTHING` names that meet the criteria.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input - I'm overwhelmed - I'm going to process all of this and let you know where I ended up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
search = 
    from c in search 
    where c.SUBTHING.All(s=>s.PROP1==1 && s.PROP2 != NULL) 
    select new {
         ThingId = c.ThingID,
         Something = c.SomeThing.Select(x=>x.Name)
     };
```

To apply filter on subitems try:

```
from product in products
where product.productid == 1
from image in product.productimages
where image.ismainimage
select image.imagename
```

From : [101 linq queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `Enumerable.Where` and an anonymous type:

```
var result = from thing in search
         from subthing in thing.subthings
         where subthing.prop1 == 1 && subthing.prop2 != null
         select new {ID = thing.ID, Name = subthing.Name};

foreach(var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID={0} Name{1}", x.ID, x.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a projection as you are querying over the parent entity (`THING`) but in the result set you want to only have a subset of its `SUBTHINGS`.

You can do it e.g. in the following way:

```
class Thing
{
    Thing(Thing original, IEnumerable<Subthing> subthings)
    {
        // Initialize based on original and set the collection
        //
        ...
    }
}
```

and then run the query like this:

```
var filtered = from c in search
               select new Thing(c, c.Subthings.Where(x => x.PROP1 == 1 && x.PROP2 != null))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure any of these answers really give you what you want (although they're close). From my understanding, you want a list of `THING`s in which at least 1 `SUBTHING` has the values you're interested in (in this case, `Prop1 == 1` and `Prop2 != null`). There are a few options here, just depends on whether you're working from a `THING` or a `SUBTHING` perspective.

**Option 1: `THING` approach.**

You're looking at any `THING` that has a `SUBTHING` with your condition. So:

```
var result = from thing in search
             where thing.Subthings.Any(tr => tr.Prop1 == 1 && tr.Prop2 != null)
             select new { ID = thing.ID, Names = thing.Subthings.Where(tr => tr.Prop1 == 1 && tr.Prop2 != null) };
```

**Option 2: `SUBTHING` approach.**

You're looking at ALL `SUBTHING`s and finding the ones where the condition is met, grouping by the ID at that point.

```
var result = from thing in search
             from sub in thing.Subthings
             where sub.Prop1 == 1 && sub.Prop2 != null
             group sub by thing.id into sg
             select new { ID = sg.Key, Names = sg.Select(tr => tr.Name) };
```

I like this approach just a little better, but still room for improvement. The reason I like this is because you find the `SUBTHING`s first, and only then will it pull the `THING` that's associated with it (instead of first having to find if any `SUBTHING` matches the criteria, and THEN selecting it).

**Option 3: Hybrid approach.**

This is a little of both. We're going to select from `SUBTHING`s either way, so might as well just perform the select. Then, if any of the projected subcollections have any elements, then we return our `THING` with the `Names`.

```
var result = from thing in search
             let names = thing.Subthings
                              .Where(sub => sub.Prop1 == 1 && sub.Prop2 != null)
                              .Select(sub => sub.Name)
             where names.Any()
             select new { ID = thing.ID, Names = names };
```

Cleanest option, in my opinion. The `Any` extension method on a collection without any parameters will return true if there are any items in the collection. Perfect for our situation.

Hope that helps, let us know what you came up with.